# Copy files to Ender 3 SD card via usb WITHOUT Octipi/Octoprint

Tags: raspberry-pi, usb, sd-card

I have a Raspberry pi that I am using for various other IOT things which is pretty busy, but I want to be able to connect my Ender3 3d printer USB to it so I can just copy files to the SD card. Right now, I'm pulling the card, copying files, replacing the card.

I know I can use Octopi/Octoprint but I'm just wondering if there is a simple way to get the ender3 SDcard to a mount point on the Raspberry pi so I can just remote into the Pi, upload the files and then start the printer. The printer sits on my desk so I can easily start printing using the dial. I'm just trying to avoid having to sneakernet the files to the sd card.

Answer (score 0):

When you open Octoprint you can drag and drop gcode files to it in order to print.

Dropping on the left hand side of the screen stores them on the Pi dropping on the right side stores them on the SD card.

You can also click the upload to SD card button on the left hand side to do the same. Just under the list of files

once those are uploaded you can just use the printer from the front panel easily and print these files. The pi only needs to be connected in order to transfer the files.

Sorry I don't have the reputation to add images to a post to show more clearly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You _should_ be able to upload images and _link_ to them in your answer, but you won't able to _embed_ them at your current reputation level. If you do upload an image, tag me in a comment and I'll happily embed them for you.

Comment: Ok will do in future thanks.